# Using ASP.NET 5 without MVC (simple Web Forms/Web Pages)

Tags: razor, webforms, asp.net-core, asp.net-webpages, dnx

The company I work for is creating pixel perfect high performance oriented large scale systems. One of our system's stack is based on simple straightforward highly tuned ASP.NET without any web controls, just simple PHP/ASP style server pages.

HTML content is mostly generated on the code behind C# environment. This is the most efficient and "performant" way of using ASP.NET (a prerequisite for us), at least according to our thorough benchmarks.

We are seriously thinking to get on with ASP.NET 5, mostly due to it's cross platform capabilities, more lightweight approach than the older ASP.NET, OWIN support and JSON based conf style.

The thing is: we won't go with MVC. It is simply a huge overkill and over-design for our needs. We are looking to work the way we do now, a simple PHP/ASP style ASP.NET but over the new framework, the ASP.NET 5.

The question is, can we work that ASP.NET WebForms style with ASP.NET 5? even if using Web Pages, how is it comparing to ASP.NET Web Forms (remember we don't use any web controls)?

Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't see an "add new item-> .aspx " files in visual studio 2015 asp net web application project.

Comment: What features are you using from Web Forms and ASP.NET?

Comment: Most of our logic is written in C# and I really want it to stay that way. That's the reason I'm using ASP.NET's Web Forms at the moment. Nothing special from WebForms, it's simply a way for me to print out C# html pages.

Comment: Remember ASP.NET 5 is a ground-up re-write, so any old benchmarking you did is not valid to draw conclusions about the performance of v5. Secondly, if all you say is true, what benefits do you aim to get from moving to ASP.NET 5? Seems like you're tightly integrated with the old ASP.NET way of doing things...

Comment: I will be benefiting by dropping some of the overhead for every request (we need to maximize the perf of each server) and obviously storing our C# solution on a Linux server will be much cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

The only available framework for generating HTML in ASP.NET 5 currently is MVC.  The next version of ASP.NET Web Pages (which is more like PHP using C# than anything) won't be included in ASP.NET 5 until the first major update after RTM. That's likely to be later in 2016.

In the meantime, you could conceivably write your own middleware to generate HTML and plug that into the ASP.NET 5 pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, just heard about this one. Sad to hear that ASP.NET 5 will support non-MVC web sites only in later release. That should be the base of MVC, the way I see it. Thanks

Comment: @Mike Your tutorials really helped me with my learning process when I first started with Asp.Net Web Dev. I still site your articles and blog to for new projects as well as a guide for other beginners. If i want an update to the stuff you wrote here in your answer... do you know what i'm supposed to search for you find more information and answers? It's been five years, and the industry is no closer to .net "Web Pages" and because of poor naming conventions, googling that really leads to dead-end search results. I dont wanna drink the MVC Kool-aid, and i need an alternative. Please and Thanks!

Comment: @user3681384 The .NET Core replacement for Web Pages is Razor Pages, although it's more like a simpler version of MVC than a .NET Core alternative to PHP. I have a site about it: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/